# PHP Track user flow

Tags: php, mysql

Well I have encountered an problem which is making my life difficult. :(
I'm trying to track detailed user flow on a website (without GA installed!).

So basically I need to have information when I select page ID35 I need to see users who landed on that page what was their flow?

So user#1 visited page ID35 => page ID31 => page ID84 => left
User#2 visited page ID35 => page83 => page124 => page1 => left
...

So 1 user can visit 2 pages, but can also visit 50 pages... I need to track in exact order how they were opened.

I have tried to create MySQL database to track everything where I had setup like this.

-ID

-ref_page (reff)

-page

But after some testing it was not producing the result I needed, because it was messing up... just too much branching (too many possible variations)..

Has anyone solved this problem of tracking user flow on a site?

Thank you!

Comment: Sound like you should just store all requests (including user id and a datetime), then just select from logs where user_id = ?

Comment: Use Google Analytics for this.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JimL I actually don't care which user... just need to know the actual path.. I have the code which saves entries to database..  but then once outputting the information there is just too much branching...



:(

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use `$_SESSION` var to store a users flow... this would require less storage in DB... less frequent inserts into the DB... and can greatly simplify the management.

The database would be redesigned to accommodate:

Table: **userflow**

Field: **user_id**
Field: **session_id**
Field: **flowStr = VARCHAR(255)**

The PHP script to track pageflow from a specific user in a particular session would be as follows ***(please note comments)***:

Document: **page_tracker.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//Initialize session pageflow array if not already set
if(!isset($_SESSION['pageflow'])){
    $_SESSION['pageflow'] = [];
}

//We need to make sure not to store repeated requests for the same page, this is a waste of space and is of no value
if(!isset($_SESSION['cur_page_id']) || $_SESSION['cur_page_id'] != THIS_PAGE_ID){
    //current page is different than the last... let's store it now
    array_push($_SESSION['pageflow'], THIS_PAGE_ID);
    $_SESSION['cur_page_id'] = THIS_PAGE_ID;
}
```

Now let's test (**NOTE**: the `CONST THIS_PAGE_ID` will need to be set in order for this to work):

Document: **sandbox.php**

```
<a href="sandbox.php">Page 0</a>
<a href="sandbox_one.php">Page 1</a>
<?php
CONST THIS_PAGE_ID = 0;

require 'page_tracker.php';

$pageflowStr = implode(';', $_SESSION['pageflow']);
echo $pageflowStr;
?>
```

Document: **sanbox_one.php**

```
<a href="sandbox.php">Page 0</a>
<a href="sandbox_one.php">Page 1</a>
<?php
CONST THIS_PAGE_ID = 1;

require 'page_tracker.php';

$pageflowStr = implode(';', $_SESSION['pageflow']);
echo $pageflowStr;
?>
```

Later, when you are ready to... you can store the value of `$pageflowStr` in the database (*userflow.flowStr*).

Hope this helps!